# Missing CRT after updated to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I uninstalled everything came with VS2010 and installed VS2012 express today.

When I tries to compile a project I created before in VS2010, everything is ok. But when the exe starts to run, it prompts that the msvcr100d.dll file is missing...

I understand that this debug version dll is not even included in any redistributable library. And normally it should included in VS2010 or VS2012. So is there any way to solve this other than reinstall VS2010 again?

I checked system32 folder, there's only msvcr110d but not msvcr100d, how to tell my project to change the dependency from 2010 to 2012

Comment: Did you try cleanning your project?

Comment: Nah.... cleaned, and nothing changed....